# @microsoft/ts-command-line: What is onDefineParameters for?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand the package [`@microsoft/ts-command-line`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/ts-command-line).

According to the docs, sample command line action is implemented like this:

```
class PushAction extends CommandLineAction {
  private _force: CommandLineFlagParameter;

  public constructor() {
    super({
      actionName: 'push',
      summary: 'Pushes a widget to the service',
      documentation: 'Your long description goes here.'
    });
  }

  protected onExecute(): Promise<void> { // abstract
    return BusinessLogic.doTheWork(this._force.value);
  }

  protected onDefineParameters(): void { // abstract
    this._force = this.defineFlagParameter({
      parameterLongName: '--force',
      parameterShortName: '-f',
      description: 'Push and overwrite any existing state'
    });
  }
}
```

What is the method `onDefineParameters` for? Why aren't the flags initialized inline?
E.g. like this:

```
class PushAction extends CommandLineAction {
  private _force = this.defineFlagParameter({
      parameterLongName: '--force',
      parameterShortName: '-f',
      description: 'Push and overwrite any existing state'
  });
  // ...
```

TypeScript also complains that `_force` is not assigned on construction when following this approach.
`onDefineParameters` seems to be a very weird design decision.